# Key items to remember for international travel

Tags: air-travel, colombia, western-europe

I'm from Columbia and I have a trip to Germany planned for the middle of May. It's the first time that I will do this kind of travel and, if it isn't obvious, I'm quite excited!.

I already have my passport ready, clothes, some money, and a schedule for when I am there. What important items am I missing?

Comment: I fear this question is asking for a [list-type answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It could work if we make one big community wiki but not for individual mini-answers.

Answer (score 1):

Electric adapter, international credit card, camera, medicines you may be using, and hygiene items like shampoo, toothbrush and toothpaste.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @hooray suggested, which is absolutely perfect:

- Printed copy of your flights, including return flight.
- Printed hotel confirmation.
- Voltage-switching chargers and cables for your camera and phone.
- Visa if you need one to enter Germany.
- Certificate of health or travel insurance you may have.
- Printed contact information in case of emergency.

Also medicines are preferred in their original packaging. Don't worry too much about hygiene products, they are easily available in Germany although much more expensive than in Colombia (I've been to both last year). For the credit-card, they use Chip-and-PIN cards.

Comment: I'd expand "don't worry too much" to anything you can buy there.  Any city that has an airport has just about anything you can possibly need.  You just have to evaluate the cost vs. the inconvenience of carrying the extra weight (or the risk of it getting lost or stolen along the way).

Comment: But I wouldn't balk at the "printed copies" itai mentioned.  I've had the "check in with cell phone" feature fail on me more than once.  Also two images of your passport: one on you to give to a bureaucrat who thinks he/she should take the actual passport from you, and one in a safe place in case that bureacrat succeeds in getting the real one and losing it.